Why does OutputStream.write wait for so long to throw java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe?
Socket mySocket = new Socket();
mySocket.setSoTimeout(8000);
mySocket.setReceiveBufferSize(iReceiveBufferSize);
mySocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(uri.getHost()), iPort), 8000);
...
mySocketOutputStream = mySocket.getOutputStream()
...
mySocketOutputStream.write(abCommand)

I wonder why it takes mySocketOutputStream.write(abCommand) 20 seconds or so to throw despite timeout set to 8 seconds as shown i the above code:
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(SocketOutputStream.java)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:144)

Could anyone shed some light on this?
